# how to bring an image in the middle position from where the text is starting?

Tags: css

When tab will select, the arrow image will appear before the tab text. But its appearing just at the left hand top corner.

Its looking like :

```
>

    abc
```

I want like:

```
>abc
```

The css is given below:

```
#navigation .selected a { background: url(../images/custom/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; }
```

I've tried like :

```
#navigation .selected a {
vertical-align: middle;

background: url(../images/custom/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; 
}
```

but its not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can influence the alignment of the background image using the [2 last parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp):

```
   #navigation .selected a {
      background: url(../images/custom/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll left center; 
     }
```

Depending on the other css present *left bottom* may get better results, or exact px-alignment may be needed.

If you have any further problems aligning the background properly, an url where the problem occurs would be of help.